# Issues with FTP on my server

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp

1. I installed FTP on my windows 2003 box
2. I created a FTP site on a ipaddress, I am not allowing anonymous access.
3. I created a user that has access to the folder c:\ftptest
4. connecting to my server using filezilla shows:
   connectiong to -0.0.0.0
   connection established, waiting for welcome message
   could not connect to server

I tried both active and passive modes.
The port on the server is open i.e. TCP 21

I can connect to other FTP sites so my locla firewall isnt' the issue.

(now I know why sys admin work is so fun!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to [debug FTP with telnet](http://www.sysadmin.md/debugging-server-services-with-telnet.html)

Comment: hm., well it connects but then it just stays blank and then I see my commadn promp again w/o a message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get into that FTP server to other sites? or is that the first one you setup?

Comment: this is the first one on this server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SFTP site using "NULL FTP Server"  and then you only need to worry about opening a single port/pinhole through your firewall.   Then, use FileZilla (or PSFTP) as a SFTP client.   You might not want to use non-encrypted FTP anyways.

I think the dual port nature of FTP and FTPS is confusing sometimes and with SFTP it is not necessary to deal with it.